# No php highlighting in .blade.php using web-mode

Tags: web-mode

there's no highlighting php into a `.blade.php` file using `web-mode`.

I just installed from MELPA and added this to my `.emacs` file:

```lisp
(require 'web-mode)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.html?\\'" . web-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.php\\'" . web-mode))

(setq web-mode-engines-alist
      '(("php"    . "\\.phtml\\'")
        ("blade"  . "\\.blade\\.php\\."))
```

[image: No php highlighting in .blade.php using web-mode]

Answer (score 0):

You've told it this:

```
  '(("php"    . "\\.phtml\\'")
    ("blade"  . "\\.blade\\.php\\."))
```

One of those things is not like the other.

Try opening a filename containing `.blade.php.` anywhere.